# Alexa Console - Add words to invoke skill / Skill invocation

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I want to specify the different words that can invoke a skill.

I know that I can run my skill with:

[start | tell | begin | open...] [Skill_Name]

But what if I want to add another word, like:

Spin [Skill_name]

The best I've found till now is this:

https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/choose-the-invocation-name-for-a-custom-skill.html

But it doesn't say how to add new words.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you able to share any more information about what you're trying to accomplish with this? What's the actual use case?

Comment: I'm trying to invoke my skill in different ways. Ex: I can say "Start my skill name", but I also want to be able to say "Spin my skill name" or "Roll my skill name".